# Count line that contain word "118-bonsplans.com" in csv file using php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have csv file "acct-2012-08-24-0001.csv" that contain many lines.I want to count all lines that contain the word "118-bonsplans.com" in line.But I do not know how to count it, I just can count all line in the csv file like the php code as below:

```
$word =  "118-bonsplans.com";
$linecount = count(file('acct-2012-08-24-0001.csv'));
echo $linecount;
```

I do not know how to do continue.Anyone help me please,
Thanks,

Comment: `grep "118-bonsplans.com" acct-2012-08-24-0001.csv | wc -l`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
count(preg_grep("/118\-bonsplans\.com/", file("acct-2012-08-24-0001.csv")));
```

The first argument to preg_grep is a regular expression pattern. The second is an array to search through. It returns an array of the items in the searched array that matched.

Comment: `count(preg_grep("/118-bonsplans\.com/", file("acct-2012-08-24-0001.csv")));`

Comment: Thanks @xdazz. I guess PHP still requires the forward slashes? Seems ridiculous, but ok.

Comment: love it - one line of code ;). the only downside might be if the file is huge to put it all at once in memory, but otherwise - genius!

Comment: @therao Your solution is definitely superior if memory constraints are an issue. I assumed a file with both a date and an incremented numeric suffix would be sufficiently small that this should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following code:

```
$handle = fopen('acct-2012-08-24-0001.csv', 'r');
$counter = 0;
if ($handle) {
while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
    if (stristr($buffer, '118-bonsplans.com')) $counter += 1;
}
fclose($handle);
}
echo $counter;
```