# Count line that contain the word "noreply@118-bonsplans.com" and "fail" in csv file using php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I have `acct-2012-08-24-0001.csv` file as below:

```
noreply@118-bonsplans.com   toulouse@texa.fr    relayed
noreply@lemeilleur-duweb.com  g.dupond@libertysurf.fr   failed
noreply@118-bonsplans.com   toulouse@texa.fr    failed
noreply@lemeilleur-duweb.com  g.dupond@libertysurf.fr   relayed
```

I want to count only `noreply@118-bonsplans.com   toulouse@texa.fr    failed` in csv file  but I do not know how to count it.Anyone know help me please, Thanks.

Comment: You asked similar qestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136000/count-line-that-contain-word-118-bonsplans-com-in-csv-file-using-php.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but this might work for you.

```
count(preg_grep("/noreply@lemeilleur-duweb.com  g.dupond@libertysurf.fr   relayed/", file("acct-2012-08-24-0001.csv")));
```

You can also check it cell by cell content with the `AND` condition in `if block`.

Answer (score 1):

use [preg_match_all()](http://cn.php.net/preg_match_all)

```
$match = preg_match_all('/noreply@118-bonsplans.com(\s+)toulouse@texa.fr(\s+)failed/i', $csv, $matches);
echo count($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do it...

```
$fp = fopen('acct-2012-08-24-0001.csv');

$count = 0;

while ($row = fgetcsv($fp)) {
    if (
        $row[0] == 'noreply@118-bonsplans.com'
        && $row[1] == 'toulouse@texa.fr'
        && $row[2] == 'failed'
    ) {
       $count++;
    }
}

echo "$count matches found";

?>
```